# VB.NET Double Question

Tags: vb.net, double, tryparse

Currently I have a Double which looks like 12.53467345 .. Now I would like to remove the numbers after the dot so i just get "12" , how could i do this? I guess with TryParse, but don't really understand how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
System.Math.Floor()
```

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

or use the `Int()` function.

```
' This code requires Option Strict Off
Dim MyNumber As Integer
MyNumber = Int(99.8)
```

[MSDN Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh29swte(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Because the decimal portion is greater than .5 Int() would actually return 13 in his example.

Comment: ? That's not what I'm seeing:
?int(12.53467345)
12.0